# Is it possible to get the DOM element of a vuejs element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue.js supplies a variable `$el` to return the whole template DOM element. Is it possible to get the "sub-element", in other words, the DOM element inside the whole template element?

For example, I want to show a floating window whose position depends on the current "mouse-over" element.

```
<div v-for="..." v-on:mouseover="showFloating(current_element)">
```

Is possible to get the DOM element "current_element"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

`<div v-for="..." v-on:mouseover="showFloating">`

```
methods:{
    showFloating(event){
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

this will give you the current element attributes`

Comment: The element itself would be `event.currentTarget`.